# Error scanning DynamoDB table

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code that scan's the DynamoDB table and returns a count of the number of people who have the key value `test = true`. For some reason, this code is not scanning the whole table. Does anyone know why?

```
var aws         = require('aws-sdk');
var config      = require('./config.js');

aws.config.update({accessKeyId: config.key, secretAccessKey: config.secret});
aws.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

function getItems() {
    var db = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    db.scan({
        TableName : config.db,
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

        var count = 0;

        for (var ii in data.Items) {
            ii = data.Items[ii];
            if (ii.setRemoveBrandingEmailOptin) {
               console.log(ii.test);
               count += 1;
            }
        }
        console.log(count);
    });
}
getItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property):

> If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size
>   limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user as
>   a LastEvaluatedKey value to continue the scan in a subsequent
>   operation. The results also include the number of items exceeding the
>   limit.

You shouldn't need to dump the entire table into your application for a simple count anyway. You're doing this in the most inefficient way possible. Try something like this:

```
db.scan({
        TableName : config.db,
        Select: 'COUNT',
        FilterExpression: "#emailOptInField = :emailOptInValue",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#emailOptInField": "setRemoveBrandingEmailOptin",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":emailOptInValue": true
        }
    }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

    var count = data.Count;
    console.log(count);
});
```

Comment: how do I use the LastEvaluatedKey to get the next set of items?

Comment: @Jasmine see my update for a better way. In general though, you should really take the time to read the documentation.

Comment: My database has a read throughout of 100/second and over 500k rows